# 2 column content in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to setup a website that gives the content editors flexibilty to add sidebar content to pages when appropriate. I have been considering adding a wysiwyg field to the Basic Page content type called sidebar that will allow them to add the sidebar content, then check for that field being set and add a sidebar block with that field value.

I've played around with Panels and not found it to be as easy to understand as I would like, and I think the content editors would be even more baffled by it.

The other method I have considered is to allow for another content type called sidebar and have a reference field that the content editor would use to relate two pieces of content together. I would need to check for the reference in the template and then add the column if there was one.

This sounds like it would be something fairly common and likely has been solved. Does anyone have a recommendation for how I should solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I would expect to create a new field in your content type called 'sidebar' or similar so that your editors don't have to leave the page to edit.

Then you could hand code into your template a content loop to pick up the field - which obviously requires theming ability - OR you could use CCK Block to put any CCK field into a block. http://drupal.org/project/cck_blocks CCK Block pushes selected CCK field into a block when it's present. Bit odd to set up but works well.

A

Comment: I have themeing ability and also I could do a module if needed. Thanks for steering me. I'll give that a try.